# Is it possible to use the new Facebook Comments plugin in iOS apps?

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

If so, what are the advantages/disadvantages for doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Brian,

You can use solution I've proposed in [my blog post](http://suhinini.me/2011/05/24/embedding-facebook-social-comments-plugin-to-an-ios-application/).

Example is configured for iPad but iPhone version is easy to create.